# Error creating bean with name 'kafkaListenerContainerFactory

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka

I am new to kafka, springboot and trying to integrate kafka and elastic search in my springboot application.

When I try to run the springboot app I see below error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'kafkaListenerContainerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/kafka/KafkaAnnotationDrivenConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.kafka.config.ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory]: Factory method 'kafkaListenerContainerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:org.springframework.kafka.config.ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory.getContainerProperties()Lorg/springframework/kafka/listener/config/ContainerProperties;
```

My pom.xml

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
            <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Application.yml

```
  security:
    enabled: true

spring:
  resources:
    chain:
      enabled: true

kafka:
  consumer:
    bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
    group-id: group-id
    auto-offset-reset: earliest
    key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
    value-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
  producer:
    bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
    key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
    value-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
```

Producer class

```
@Service
public class Producer {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Producer.class);
    private static  final  String topic = "users";

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

    public void sendMessage(History t){
        logger.info("Inside send message to topic");
        this.kafkaTemplate.send(topic,"HelloWorld");
    }

}
```

Consumer.java

```
package com.springboot.kafka;

import com.springboot.model.History;
import com.springboot.repository.HistoryRepository;
import org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.types.Field;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class Consumer  {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Consumer.class);
    private static  final  String topic = "users";


    @KafkaListener(topics = topic,groupId = "group-id")
    public void consume (String t){
        logger.info("Message read as " + t);

    }
}
```

Application.properties:

```
logging.level.sql=info
logging.file = /var/tmp/SpringBootAppLog.log
spring.datasource.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-name=my-application
spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-nodes=localhost:9200
```

Any idea on what I am missing on. Any leads will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Probably you are mixing kafka version. Check the exception (at the end). The method being called does not exist. Either you are missing a dependency or using the wrong version.

Comment: you have `Application.properties` & `Application.yml`? It is normally one or the other. My guess would be that Spring isn't loading your `application.yml` at all.

Comment: why do you use the StringDeserializer for the value-serializer? I would assume the StringSerializer should be used. Maybe therefore a serial method is missing?

Answer (score 0):

You should check your full error log (stacktrace). In my case the problem was caused by a *`java.io.FileNotFoundException`* further below.
Often you find your 'real' problem at the end of the stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

Your `value-serializer` uses a `StringDeserializer`. I would assume this should be the `StringSerializer`. Therefore, a serialize method for the value missing.